# Importing static image in project with image loader using next-image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

The project I'm working is using an image loader configured in its next.config.js.

The thing is, I don't have access to its cloud so I can't upload it, so I need to import the image statically from on the project.

How can I import an static image in the project, since its configured to use a loader?

I tried importing it in the file I'm working, but can't manage to make it work.

I'm using the Image component, and running the project locally.
The project is configured to use the Cloudinary Loader and no CSP is configured.

Comment: Could you reiterate your question with a few more details?

Are you using the Image tag? Have you configured CSP in your next.config.js? Where are you running your Nextjs project?

A few more details! :D

Comment: @404answernotfound I made the edits. Thanks for the insight

Comment: You can use the [`loader`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loader) prop on the `next/image` directly to override the Cloudinary loader on a per-image basis.